# Extract sting inside nested brackets and its pre/postfix Python

Tags: python, algorithm, brackets

I am trying to extract the string inside nested brackets and product them.

Let's say I have following string

```
string = "(A((B|C)D|E|F))"
```

According to the answer in [Extract string inside nested brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456603/extract-string-inside-nested-brackets)

I can extract the string inside nested brackets, but for my case it's different since I have `"D"` at the end of bracket so this is the result from the code. It looks so far from my desired output

```
['B|C', 'D|E|F', 'A']
```

This is my desired output

```
[[['A'],['B|C'],['D']], [['A'],['E|F']']]     # '|' means OR
```

Do you have any recommandation, should I implement by using regular expression or just run through all given string?

So it can leads to my final result, that is

```
"ABD"
"ACD"
"AE"
"AF"
```

In this point, I will use `itertools.product`

Comment: your `string` is in a bit of a confusing format - what suggests that `AE` is an output? If the input was, for example, `"A((B|C)D|E|F)"` that would perhaps be a little easier to make sense of

Comment: @asongtoruin My bad, my input should be `"(A((B|C)D|E|F))"` like your suggestions

Comment: In your input string = "(A((B|C)D|E|F))"
D, E, F are all considered equal candidates, nothing differentiate D from E or F. I would suggest put one extra brace as suggested by @boated_tw according to your code implementation.

Comment: I don't really understand your desired output. I would think that `[['A', [['B|C'], 'D|E|F']]]` would be a more meaningful result. This is much easier to achieve.

Comment: @ssm I think so. But in my actual input, is a string for drawing a syntactic tree in label bracket formatting which generated from Parser. So it does matter to have that desired output.

Comment: In your input you have 3 `|`, while in your desired output you only have two. So is the list structure somehow inferring an OR relationship somewhere? If so, can you explain this rule? And then why not apply this for all `|` occurrences? The rules for generating what you want are not clear to me.

Comment: @trincot 
I think the given example still need to fix.
But for the rule so far, If I separate the given string into segments:
"(A    ((B|C)D    |   E    |F    ))":
(1) "A" can concatenate with (B or C)D which is BD or BD --> ABD, ACD (2 ways)
and
(2) "A" can concatenate with E --> AE (1 way)
and
(3) "A" can concatenate with F --> AF (1 way)
Then the given string generated (2+1+1) possible patterns.

The reason why I need that desired output because the desired output is needed for `itertools.product1` to get the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the language precisely, but it looks like arbitrary nested brackets are allowed. It's not a regular language. I wouldn't recommend to parse it with regular expression (it might be possible as regular expressions in python are not truly regular, but even if it's possible, it'll probably be a mess).

I'd recommend to define a context-free grammar for your language and parse it instead. Here's how you can do it:

```
EXPR -> A EXPR (an expression is an expression preceded by an alphabetic character)
EXPR -> (LIST) EXPR (an expression is a list followed by an expression)
EXPR -> "" (an expression can be an empty string)

LIST -> EXPR | LIST (a list is an expression followed by "|" followed by a list)
LIST -> EXPR (or just one expression)
```

This grammar can be parsed by a simple top-down recursive parser which works in linear time. Here's a sample implementation:

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.pos = 0

    def get_cur_char(self):
        """
        Returns the current character or None if the input is over
        """
        return None if self.pos == len(self.data) else self.data[self.pos]

    def advance(self):
        """
        Moves to the next character of the input if the input is not over.
        """
        if self.pos < len(self.data):
            self.pos += 1

    def get_and_advance(self):
        """
        Returns the current character and moves to the next one.
        """
        res = self.get_cur_char()
        self.advance()
        return res

    def parse_expr(self):
        """
        Parse the EXPR according to the speficied grammar.
        """
        cur_char = self.get_cur_char()
        if cur_char == '(':
            # EXPR -> (LIST) EXPR rule
            self.advance()
            # Parser the list and the rest of the expression and combines
            # the result.
            prefixes = self.parse_list()
            suffices = self.parse_expr()
            return [p + s for p in prefixes for s in suffices]
        elif not cur_char or cur_char == ')' or cur_char == '|':
            # EXPR -> Empty rule. Returns a list with an empty string without
            # consuming the input.
            return ['']
        else:
            # EXPR -> A EXPR rule.
            # Parses the rest of the expression and prepends the current 
            # character.
            self.advance()
            return [cur_char + s for s in self.parse_expr()]

    def parse_list(self):
        """
        Parser the LIST according to the speficied grammar.
        """
        first_expr = self.parse_expr()
        # Uses the LIST -> EXPR | LIST rule if the next character is | and
        # LIST -> EXPR otherwise    
        return first_expr + (self.parse_list() if self.get_and_advance() == '|' else [])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = "(A((B|C)D|E|F))"
    parser = Parser(string)
    print('\n'.join(parser.parse_expr()))
```

If you're not familiar with this technique, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing).

This implementation is not the most efficient one (for instance, it uses lists explicitly instead of iterators), but it's a good starting point.

Comment: You are corrected about don't use regular expression. After I tested with regular expression it takes too long to conduct for covering all possible case. This is really good starting point and also cover most of my actual input so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go for a solution that targets the final result immediately. So a function that would make this transformation:

```
input: "(A((B|C)D|E|F))"
output: ['ABD', 'ACD', 'AE', 'AF']
```

Here is the code I would propose:

```
import re

def tokenize(text):
    return re.findall(r'[()|]|\w+', text)

def product(a, b):
    return [x+y for x in a for y in b] if a and b else a or b

def parse(text):
    tokens = tokenize(text)

    def recurse(tokens, i):
        factor = []
        term = []
        while i < len(tokens) and tokens[i] != ')':
            token = tokens[i]
            i += 1
            if token == '|':
                term.extend(factor)
                factor = []
            else:
                if token == '(':
                    expr, i = recurse(tokens, i)
                else:
                    expr = [token]
                factor = product(factor, expr)
        return term+factor, i+1

    return recurse(tokens, 0)[0]

string = "(A((B|C)D|E|F))"

print(parse(string))
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GsQQ)