# Extract code between the function using regxr or any suitable way in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, visual-studio

**Goal / Need help to: extract code inside the Functions as well as Class using regex  (code inside the curly brackets {} )**

However, its okay to use some other library other than regex to find the solution

**Programming language**: Python

**Issues**: not all the code inside the function is extracted (it partially provides the code inside the class.
Test File: JAVA code (merge sort algorithm)

**My python code**: ( in the code, I am trying to extract code between class but not working and also want to do for functions)

```
f=open("MergeSort.java","r")
code=f.read()
className="MergeSort"
results = set()
regxStr=className+' \{.*?\}'
codeTraverse=code.replace("\n", " ")+""
codeTraverse=codeTraverse.replace("\t"," ")
re.findall(regxStr, codeTraverse)
print("------------------**************------------answers",re.findall(regxStr, codeTraverse))
print("finish*******")
```

**Output picture:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo5oN.png)

**Target File:** JAVAFILE that i am trying to extract the code from is  follows

```
/* Java program for Merge Sort Code taken from geeks for geeks*/
class MergeSort
{

    void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
    {
        
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;

        int L[] = new int[n1];
        int R[] = new int[n2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
            L[i] = arr[l + i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
            R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        int k = l;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while (i < n1) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while (j < n2) {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }


    void sort(int arr[], int l, int r)
    {
        if (l < r) {
        
            int m =l+ (r-l)/2;

        
            sort(arr, l, m);
            sort(arr, m + 1, r);

        
            merge(arr, l, m, r);
        }
    }


    static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = { 12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7 };

        System.out.println("Given Array");
        printArray(arr);

        MergeSort ob = new MergeSort();
        ob.sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

        System.out.println("\nSorted array");
        printArray(arr);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**
So lets say if I  request for function "printArray" from python. I am trying to get all the code inside the function "printArray" using regxr and similarily, when I request code inside the class name, I should be able to get code inside the class.

I did take a look over regex code on stackoverflow like following,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456603/extract-string-inside-nested-brackets
But I am still not able to use it efficiently.

I am stuck and need some help from stackoverflow community. Thank you and please.

Comment: There is no single regex that can parse the Java language as far as I know.

Comment: any other way in order to achieve my goal, any python library or any code sample, I can use ?please help

Answer (score 1):

`r"(?<=\{)(\D*|\d*)(?=\})"gm`

This should grab everything that's not a digit `\D` (including new lines), and everything that is a digit `\d`, between curly braces. This also excludes the curly braces themselves with positive look behind `(?<=\{)` and positive look ahead `(?=\})`.

Comment: it is not working, set is empty, this expression is not working please provide full code. and also provide how did where you able to get with respect to classname+regexstring. Please refer to the goal and code of the question.

Comment: Apologies, that regex worked with some java code I tested. `(?<=\{)(\X*)(?=\})` works with the PCRE regex engine, but don't think will work with Python. Have a look at https://regex101.com/. You can paste in the stuff you're trying to match, and quickly try different regexes. There's also allot of interactive information there.